# Need help finding whats wrong with this code. [2 username and password]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a two username and password program, and it isn't working...

```
import time
import random
import sys


p1="false"
p2="false"
realuser1="Rion"
realpass1="Sadiku"
realuser2="Player"
realpass2="Two"


def rion():
    user1=input("Enter your username: ")
    pass1=input("Enter your password: ")
    if user1 == realuser1 and pass1 == realpass1:
        print("User authenticated: ")
        p1="true"
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")
        sys.exit


def player2():
    user2=input("Enter your username: ")
    pass2=input("Enter your password: ")
    if user2 == realuser2 and pass2 == realpass2:
        print("User authenticated: ")
        p2="true"
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")
        sys.exit


rion()
player2()

if p2 == "true" and p1 == "true":
    print("Both players have been authenticated")
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print("Something happened. Try again later")
```

when the username and passwords of both p1 and p2 are entered correctly, it still executes the "else:" line at the end.

Comment: First of all, a major issue I'd see (among other things) is the fact that your functions neither take input parameters nor return something. They just take variables from the outer scope. It will become very hard to understand what's going on in a bigger program! Then, your code works for me *as it is*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P1 and p2 are of type strings(immutable).
So their values will not get reflected in outer scope.

One approach is to use global (Which might not be a good practice)

```
import time
import random
import sys


p1="false"
p2="false"
realuser1="Rion"
realpass1="Sadiku"
realuser2="Player"
realpass2="Two"


def rion():
    user1=input("Enter your username: ")
    pass1=input("Enter your password: ")
    if user1 == realuser1 and pass1 == realpass1:
        print("User authenticated: ")
        global p1
        p1="true"

    else:
        print("Something went wrong")
        sys.exit


def player2():
    user2=input("Enter your username: ")
    pass2=input("Enter your password: ")
    if user2 == realuser2 and pass2 == realpass2:
        print("User authenticated: ")
        global p2
        p2="true"

    else:
        print("Something went wrong")
        sys.exit


rion()
player2()

if p2 == "true" and p1 == "true":
    print("Both players have been authenticated")
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print("Something happened. Try again later")
```

Comment: Thanks your code worked for me. It must have been because the variables were local.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. You dont need to import time and random. p1 and p2 statments are "false" at beginng. There is no sense to make them "true" later. Dont need to define as "false". In the same time "sys.exit" have no task.
I am really get hard to understand your codes. Try the recursion:

```
import sys


realuser1="Rion"
realpass1="Sadiku"
realuser2="Player"
realpass2="Two"


def rion():
    user1=input("Enter your username: ")
    pass1=input("Enter your password: ")
    if user1 == realuser1 and pass1 == realpass1:
        print("User authenticated: ")
        p1="true"
        return p1
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")


def player2():
    user2=input("Enter your username: ")
    pass2=input("Enter your password: ")
    if user2 == realuser2 and pass2 == realpass2:
        print("User authenticated: ")
        p2="true"
        return p2
    else:
        print("Something went wrong")


rion()
player2()

if p2 == "true" and p1 == "true":
    print("Both players have been authenticated")
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print("Something happened. Try again later")
```